# Importing a txt file and reversing the lines as an output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in python and wanted to know how I can set up a function to accept a file as a parameter but then the output should produce it inn reversed lines

for example, if the text file contained the following:

```
"Jack and Jill went up the hill
to fetch a pail of water
jack fell down and broke his crown"
```

The output should be

```
"to fetch a pail of water
jack fell down and broke his crown 
Jack and Jill went up the hill"
```

Comment: Shouldn't `jack fell down and broke his crown` be the 1st line in your output?

Comment: It is not an answer, but you might consider using command line tool `tac` from `coreutils`. It does exactly what you want, but in command line (or you popen the process). If you need python, then file_out.write(file_in.redlines().reverse()).

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fr, open('test_out.txt', 'w') as fw:
    content = fr.readlines()
    for item in content[::-1]:
        fw.write("%s\n" % item.rstrip('\n'))
```

**Input File**

```
Jack and Jill went up the hill
to fetch a pail of water
jack fell down and broke his crown
```

**Output File**

```
jack fell down and broke his crown
to fetch a pail of water
Jack and Jill went up the hill
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the first solution, you can also use [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) here:

```
with open("example.txt") as fp, open("output.txt", mode="w") as fw:
    for line in reversed(fp.readlines()):
        fw.write(line.rstrip() + "\n")
```